# Convert windows path to Linux path

Tags: ruby, path

Currently I am getting the path as `\\documents\videos\form.mov` but need to change the path to `/documents/videos/form.mov`. I have tried using path seperator and as well as `split`. But it does not allow to split the path as '\' is an escape character.

Please can anyone help me in this.

Comment: How are you "getting the path"? What have you tried (show your code)?

Comment: I don't have experience with ruby, but generally you can escape an escape character by doubling it ("\\" will match a literal backslash character).

Comment: "But it does not allow to split the path as '\' is an escape character."

Well, that part is an easy fix. Just use two backslashes (the first one escapes the second).

Comment: Check this post out, it may solve your problem. [Ruby: windows path conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931022/ruby-windows-path-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
path = '\\\\documents\videos\form.mov'

new_path = path.gsub /\\+/, '/'

puts path, new_path
```

**output**

```
\\documents\videos\form.mov
/documents/videos/form.mov
```

Here is a copy of an `irb` session

```
E:\Ruby\source>irb --simple-prompt
>> path = '\\\\documents\videos\form.mov'
=> "\\\\documents\\videos\\form.mov"
>> new_path = path.gsub /\\+/, '/'
=> "/documents/videos/form.mov"
>>
```

Comment: Here you have used path in the single quotes...so it will change the path as '\\\\documents\\videos\form.mov' hence it is easy to convert but in my case....I am getting the path from user...i.e user is entering the path so he will not enter the path in single quotes. When I tried your solution for the path it is giving me output as 

`path = "\\\\documents\videos\form.mov"
 => "\\\\documents\videos\form.mov" 
2.0.0p0 :031 > new_path = path.gsub /\\+/, '/'
 => "/documents\videos\form.mov" 
`

Comment: Your version of my code isn't working becuase you are using double quotes. The quotes don't "change the path". The choice of quotes simply determine what special sequences are translated, so within double quotes `\n` means a newline, which inside single quotes it means the rwo characters `\n`. If your user is entering `\\documents\videos\form.mov` as input to a prompt then that is exactly what your string will contain (with a newline at the end, which you need to `chomp`. Please describe more about your program if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers didn't meet my expectations, so I had to roll my own. Here is the module and its unit test.

```
module ConvertWindowsPath
  def convert_windows_path windows_path
    manipulated_windows_path = windows_path.clone
    unix_path = ""
    if windows_path.start_with? "\\\\" #it's on some network thing
      unix_path = "//"
      manipulated_windows_path = manipulated_windows_path[2..-1]
    elsif manipulated_windows_path.start_with? "\\"
      unix_path = "/"
    end
    unix_path += manipulated_windows_path.split("\\").join("/")
    unix_path += "/" if manipulated_windows_path.end_with?("\\")
    unix_path
  end
end

require 'test/unit'

class ConvertWindowsPathTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include ConvertWindowsPath
  def setup
    @expectations = {
      "C:\\" => "C:/",
      "\\\\vmware-host\\Shared Folders\\Foo\\bar-baz" => "//vmware-host/Shared Folders/Foo/bar-baz",
      "D:\\Users\\ruby\\Desktop\\foo.txt" => "D:/Users/ruby/Desktop/foo.txt",
      "z:\\foo\\bar\\" => "z:/foo/bar/"
    }
  end
  def test_expectations
    @expectations.each do |windows_path, expected_unix_path|
      assert_equal expected_unix_path, convert_windows_path(windows_path)
    end
  end
end
```